# Center Dropdown Navigation Menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, navigation

I'm needing to center my navigation menu. Currently the text is at the left and I'm not sure what I must change in my code in order to move it.

Could you check out my page and see what needs to be done? http://www.studywithstyleblog.com

And here is some of the code...

```
#cssnav ul {
    background: $(tabs.background.color) $(tabs.background.gradient) repeat-x scroll 0 -800px;
    _background-image: none; /* Template Designer - Change Menu Background */
    height: 40px; /* Change Height of Menu */
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#cssnav li {
    float: none; /* none = centre */
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
}

    #cssnav li a {
        background: $(tabs.background.color) $(tabs.background.gradient) repeat-x scroll 0 -800px;
        _background-image: none; /* Template Designer - Change Menu Background */
        display: block;
        margin: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        font: $(tabs.font); /* Template Designer - Change Font Type, Size, Etc */
        text-decoration: none;
    }

#cssnav > ul > li > a {
    color: $(tabs.text.color); /* Template Designer - Change Font Color */
}

#cssnav ul ul a {
    color: $(tabs.text.color); /* Template Designer - Change Color */
}

#cssnav li > a:hover, #cssnav ul li:hover {
    color: $(tabs.selected.text.color); /* Template Designer - Change Font Color on Hover */
    background-color: $(tabs.selected.background.color); /* Template Designer - Change Font Background on Hover */
    text-decoration: none;
}

#cssnav li ul {
    background: $(tabs.background.color) $(tabs.background.gradient) repeat-x scroll 0 -800px;
    _background-image: none; /* Template Designer - Change Menu Background */
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: -5px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px; /* Change Width Of DropDown Menu */
    z-index: 9999;
}

#cssnav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

#cssnav li li {
    background: $(tabs.background.color) $(tabs.background.gradient) repeat-x scroll 0 -800px;
    _background-image: none; /* Template Designer - Change Background */
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 300px; /* Change Width Of DropDown Menu */
}

#cssnav li:hover li a {
    background: #FFFFFF; /* Template Designer - Change Background of Link on Hover */
}

#cssnav li ul a {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

    #cssnav li ul a:hover, #cssnav li ul li:hover > a {
        color: $(tabs.selected.text.color); /* Template Designer - Change Text Color on Hover */
        background-color: $(tabs.selected.background.color); /* Template Designer - Change Background on Hover */
        border: 0px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

/*-------- Begin Drop Down Menu -------*/

Thank you in advance!

Comment: www.studywtihstyleblog.com not working

Comment: Post html&css or demo (jsfiddle or whatever)

Comment: Better post the problem ad jsfiddle.com otherwise one could think its an attempt to get clicks on your blog

Comment: I promise it's not. I honestly just don't even know what part of the code I need to post on there... or on here. Would it be the #cssnav and #menus sections?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css after your existing css. You could also go back and make these changes to your exiting CSS;

```
#menus {
  text-align: center;
}
#menus > li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**NOTE** - You will need to play around with your borders on the main menus, and also the sub menu positioning. In future try to add your code to a jsfiddle and post that, this lets us give you a realtime example of the effects of the code we suggest.

Comment: Those changes worked and centered the main menu and sub menu. Thanks! But now how exactly do I center the text in the sub menu tabs?